# How to fix magento 2.3 openlog() security error

Tags: magento2, error

This is my error. How to fix this?

> main.CRITICAL: Warning: openlog() has been disabled for security
>   reasons in
>   /vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/SyslogHandler.php on line
>   62

Comment: Your PHP version please?

Comment: PHP Version 7.1.30